# How to show part of other website in my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Suppose in other website exists a `div element` with a `table` in it.
The content of `div element` changes during the time.
I want to show that `div element` and it's contents in my website.
Is it possible using Asp or jquery or javascript or other ways?
I have heard about socket programming.

**EDIT:**
I don't want whole webpage. just a part of it.I think Iframe can't help me.

Comment: Create a server side script which actually access the above said web page. In PHP we can use Curl and in Python urllib2. Write a Ajax function which calls this script. We may have to write a parser since the script will be garbing the entire page. Get required div and format as you wish return it as the reply to Ajax

Comment: Or will this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ for you ?

Answer (score 2):

With plain JS/Browser programming, use iframes since:

- AJAX cannot do cross-domain unless the remote server supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) which usually does not.
- Sockets, JSON or JSONP need some server logic to interface with your code, which I highly doubt is implemented on the remote server.

So unless you control the remote server where you *can* implement logic or allow CORS, there's little you can do about it.

OR...

If you have access to your server, you can have your server act as a proxy and read the remote page for you. The server is not bound to the [Same Origin Policy (SOP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) thus can read remote pages. And with this, you can use AJAX requests your server.

It runs like

```
Your browser <-AJAX-> your server <-wget/curl/fopen/whatever-> remote server
```

And the request url to your server typically looks like (unencoded):

```
http://mysite.com/remoteread.php?remote_url=http://myremotesite.com/thispage.php
```

then `remoteread.php` reads the remote page, and simply "relays" the reply to your browser.

Found a [article from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) that explains the methodology in more detail

Comment: Could you send me an article or a link to explain me more details?

Comment: It's basically common knowledge, so it just came from the top of my head. But the more general topic is titled ["Bypassing the Same Origin Policy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)